# How to make Visual Studio ASP.NET project ready to be hosted in a server.

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I got an ASP.NET project. I'm going to send the project to a server company where they will host it. How do I prepare it to be hosted? I assume I cant simply send the whole project to them. What are the steps to prepare the project to be readable in their server?

This is my first project, never done it before.

- Used Visual Studio 2015, WebForm/ASP.NET.
- It's going to be hosted via a server company, no clue about anything about their servers.
- Also got a MS Access database in App_Data folder within the project.

PS: I found "Publish" by right-clicking the project in Visual Studio's 'Solution Explorer'. I've been checking out [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd394698%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) but it's really confusing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've used Publish before for an MVC app and it is alright. Makes the work a little easier.  But the core components you need, from my experience and what I know are:

* Global.asax
* Bin folder
* your Scripts and Content folder
* Web.config
* The .aspx files

You'd probably also need the App_Data folder as well if you have anything in there

Comment: Publish is what you want.

Comment: Here is one way: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y1404zt(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @StephenMcDowell In publish, all I see via Publish is "Profile" and I can select between 'Microsoft Azure App service', 'Import' and 'Custom'. Is "Import" option the way to go?

Comment: @MikeCheel is it File System, Web Deploy or FTP method I want to use? They said I should zip the project(ready to be published) and send it to them.

Comment: If the agreement you have is to provide a zip then you select 'Custom'.  From there the publish method would be 'File System'.  You'll have to zip the output yourself.

Comment: Sorry it took me a bit to get back to you. Just like Stephen said, create a file system profile and publish it then zip.by hand. Yoi should look through the outputs and make sure you only send what you need.

Answer (score 0):

When you publish an application, most of the time it will run just as it does when you debug it, but on the server. All the binaries are copied there, with the Web.config, and most like all you have in your application, but the source code will not be avaiable of course. You don't need to send the application to the company which will host your application, most likely they will give you the server address where your application will be published, they will create an account for you, with some permissions, and credentials. And of course, you can read more about [IIS server](http://www.iis.net/), it will be pretty relevant to you, and you can configure yourself a server where you can publish your application, just to see how it works.

Comment: They asked me to zip my project. I'm only familiar with IIS since that's how I test my project when I debug it. However I don't think they will give me the address otherwise they would do so in the beginning. Trough "Publish method", there's File System, FTP and Web Deploy. Which method is most suitable?

Answer (score 0):

Set up your own application on your own IIS and experiment locally until you have all stuff in place. Then copy to you hosting environment.

Later on you can script this process to have full control over what you need in dev and prod respectively.